# When did the imperial army leave Magdeburg after the sack?

Tags: thirty-years-war

After the sack (in 1631) of Magdeburg for how long did the imperial army stay in the city? Did they leave a garrison behind?

EDIT

Tilly who led the forces in Magdeburg later led them on July 22nd against the Swedes at Werben. That's about 130km, so they would need at least 4-5 days to reach it. So that would put it between May 21st and July 17th. That's still pretty wide.

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: Have you read [Sack of Magdeburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sack_of_Magdeburg)? What conclusions can you draw from this article? For example, the looting didn't end until the 24th so your 21st May date needs revising.

Comment: The German Wikipedia states that after the sack, Tilly lingered with his troops in the vicinity of the destroyed city, unsure how to proceed, a situation that Pappenheim found highly frustrating.

Comment: @Lars Bosteen Yes, I read the wiki, but i missed that detail. Thanks, that narrows it from the lower end. I'm more curious about the upper hand. The other comment about lingering is useful, but it would be great to have a link to source with the date.